# Uploading files in rest api with Yii2

Tags: rest, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have this method to upload files in an api rest:

```
public function actionUpload() {
    $postdata = fopen($_FILES['data']['tmp_name'], "r");
    /* Conseguir la extensión del fichero */
    $extension = substr($_FILES['data']['name'], strrpos($_FILES['data']['name'], '.'));

    /* generar un único nombre */
    $filename = $this->documentPath . uniqid() . $extension;

    /* Abrir un fichero para escribir */
    $fp = fopen($filename, "w");

    /* Leer los datos de 1 KB a la vez y escribirlos */
    while ($data = fread($postdata, 1024))
        fwrite($fp, $data);

    /* Cerrar los streams */
    fclose($fp);
    fclose($postdata);

    /* Resultado mandado al cliente */
    $result = new UploadResult;
    $result->filename = $filename;
    $result->document = $_FILES['data']['name'];
    $result->create_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    return $result;
}
```

When I try to see if it works with the postman, I have this error message:

"message": "Undefined index: data",

If on the postman I have this:

[image: Postman with the variable data]

I don't understand why I have this error message. Could you help me?.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why not use the UploadedFile class? Already part of Yii.

Comment: This would be the rest api part. I wouldn't need in this case a form.

Comment: I believe it would solve your problem. Check out this static method: UploadedFile::getInstanceByName()

Comment: It did it :). Thanks so much